# How do I simultaneously decrease resolution and increase DPI for an image on the command line?

Tags: command-line, imagemagick

I'm thinking ImageMagick should be able to do it, but have yet to be able to figure out how. The lack of English Google doesn't help (I'm in China right now).

I'd also appreciate comments about whether this method works for sacrificing resolution to increase "real" DPI.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the DPI of an image, the resolution (in inches) automatically changes accordingly, while the size (in pixels) keeps the same. Therefore commands like `convert -units PixelsPerInch -density 600 input.png output.png` may suit your needs, in which 600 is the target DPI.